# Is there a more efficient way of mapping a list of items to a list of pairs in a certain way?

Tags: kotlin, collections

source data: Array<File>

target return data: List<Pair<File,File>>

The source data (Array<File>) contains a list of jpegs of a book in the form of (Scan0001.jpg, Scan0002.jpg, ..., Scan000n.jpg). The first file (Scan0001.jpg) is always the front cover of the book and the last file (Scan000n.jpg) is always the back cover of the book. The variable files in the following code snippet is an Array<File!> that only contains jpeg files in the form of Scanxxxx.jpg.

I want to create Pairs of Files of the pages, with the following rules:

1) The covers (front, back) should be always be Pair<File,null> (File being Scan0001.jpg, Scan000n.jpg respectively)

2) If the non-cover pages are uneven (meaning the last page doesn't have a pair) it should be Pair<File,null> (File being Scan000n-1.jpg)

3) The front cover should always be the first File Pair and the back cover always be the last

The following code works, but I feel there is space for improvement in terms of a more efficient or more clean code

```
val files = selectedFolder.listFiles()
val preliminaryResult = files.toMutableList()
val result = mutableListOf<Pair<File?,File?>>()

result.add(Pair(preliminaryResult.first(),null))
preliminaryResult.removeAt(0)

result.add(Pair(preliminaryResult.last(),null))
preliminaryResult.removeAt(preliminaryResult.size-1)

result.addAll(preliminaryResult.map{
    if(preliminaryResult.indexOf(it) % 2 == 0) {
        Pair(it,preliminaryResult.getOrNull(preliminaryResult.indexOf(it)+1))
    } else {
        Pair(null,null)
    }
})

result.removeAll{
    it == Pair(null,null)
}

result.add(result[1])
result.removeAt(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the nulls you need first so you can use `zipWithNext` uninterrupted.

```
val result = selectedFolder.listFiles().toMutableList<File?>().apply {
    add(1, null) // for front cover
    if (0 == size % 2)
        add(size - 1, null) // for odd inner last page
    add(null) // for back cover
}.zipWithNext()
    .run { slice(indices step 2) }
```

Comment: hey, the problem with that is, that it creates result like (A,B), (B,C), (C,D), etc. so every page appears twice. But by replacing zipWithNext() with chunked(2).map{it[0] to it[1]} it produces the required result. Thank you! edit: if you edit your answer, i'll mark it correct :)

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I edited it with a different way to do it.